PowerApps PDF viewer can't open PDF files
I'm busy with a task where I made a simple PDF file. Before it's sent to sharepoint to store and it's still just a variable, the PDF viewer is more than happy to open it for me.
Set(
    varMyPDF;
    PDF(
        PDFtosubmit;
        {
            Orientation: PaperOrientation.Portrait;
            Size: PaperSize.A4;
            Margin: "20px";
            ExpandContainers: true
        }
    )
)
And
makePDF.Run({file:{name: "Name"; contentBytes: varMyPDF}})

On the side of the same screen I made a vertical gallery with the content of a the sharepoint document library where I saved the aforemantioned file. I tried to approach with two solution.

Vertical Gallery - OnSelect:
Set(varMyPDF; ThisItem.'Koppeling naar item')

In this first case the viewer shows: 'the PDF can't be opened - open in browser instead'

Vertical Gallery - OnSelect:
Set(varMyPDF; getPDF.Run(ThisItem.'Id ({Identifier})').result)

Here I made a flow (getPDF):

powerapps trigger with item ID as arg.

Sharepoint - get filecontent

Compose (from base64 to binary)

Respond to power app - result as text


The viewer is showing the following message: 'the PDF can't be open - check if the PDF is coming through https connection'


Well, I don't know where to now. I couldn't find a way to force https response in powerapps flow. What now?
